# L.DomUtil.get() modifiers don't update HTML data

Tags: popup, leaflet, marker, leaflet.draw

Creating a map with markers displayed on it. When clicking a marker, this one has to display a Popup. I extended the L.Popup like this

```
L.InfrastructurePopup = L.Popup.extend({

    options: {
        template : "<form id='popup-form'>\
        <div>\
        <label for='problem'>Problem</label>\
        <textarea id='problem' rows='4' cols='46' placeholder='Type your text here'></textarea>\
        </div>\
        <div>\
        <label for='solution'>Solution</label>\
        <textarea id='solution' rows='4' cols='46' placeholder='Type your text here'></textarea>\
        </div>\
        <button id='button-submit' class='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Submit</button>\
        </form>",
    },

    setContent: function () {
        this._content = this.options.template;
        this.update();
        return this;
    },

    initializeForm(layer, callback)
    {
        var problem = L.DomUtil.get('problem');
        problem.textContent = layer.options.problem ? layer.options.problem : "";
        problem.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
        {
            layer.options.problem = problem.value;
        });
        var solution = L.DomUtil.get('solution');
        solution.textContent = layer.options.solution ? layer.options.solution : "";
        solution.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
        {
            layer.options.solution = solution.value;
        });

        var buttonSubmit = L.DomUtil.get('button-submit');
        buttonSubmit.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
        {
            callback(layer);
        });
    }
});

L.infrastructurePopup = function (options, source)
{
    return new L.InfrastructurePopup(options, source);
};
```

I linked it into a custom Marker called InfrastructureMarker that has one and only popup , a InfrastructurePopup. So when it calls the openPopup() function it loads the popup on the map [ map.addLayer(popup) ] and give me the correct datas thanks to method initializeForm() that I call after the addLayer(popup) method.

```
L.Map.include({

    openInfrastructurePopup: function (layer, callback)
    {
        this.closePopup();

        layer._popup._isOpen = true;

        this.addLayer(layer._popup);

        layer._popup.initializeForm(layer, callback);
    }
});

L.InfrastructureMarker = L.Marker.extend({

    openPopup: function (callback)
    {
        if (this._popup && this._map && !this._map.hasLayer(this._popup))
        {
            this._popup.setLatLng(this._latlng);
            this._map.openInfrastructurePopup(this, callback);
        }

        return this;
    },
    togglePopup: function (callback)
    {
        if (this._popup)
        {
            if (this._popup._isOpen)
            {
                this._popup._isOpen = false;
                this.closePopup();
            }
            else
            {
                this.openPopup(callback);
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    bindPopup: function (callback, options)
    {
        var anchor = L.point(this.options.icon.options.popupAnchor || [0, 0]);

        anchor = anchor.add(L.Popup.prototype.options.offset);

        if (options && options.offset)
        {
            anchor = anchor.add(options.offset);
        }

        options = L.extend({offset: anchor}, options);

        if (!this._popupHandlersAdded)
        {
            this
                .on('click', () =>  {this.togglePopup(callback)}, this)
                .on('remove', this.closePopup, this)
                .on('move', this._movePopup, this);
            this._popupHandlersAdded = true;
        }

        this._popup = new L.infrastructurePopup(options, this).setContent();

        return this;
    },
});

L.infrastructureMarker = function (latlng, options)
{
    return new L.InfrastructureMarker(latlng, options);
};
```

But if I decide to click on one marker, then on another one without closing the first one, it loads the template, but initializeForm(callback) doesn't change the datas. I checked all the datas to know if it was empty or something but everything worked, I absolutely don't know where the problem is. I suppose the popup is not yet set on the DOM before my L.DomUtils.get fire but I shouldn't see undefined elements in console.log when I'm getting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found what was happening :

Actually, when the L.map calls its closePopup function , it destroys the layer. 
So after that, it creates a new one to display. BUT the remaining HTML from the previous kind of still exists.

So I finally bound exact same Ids to two HTML tags. Heresy !

My solution became what's next :

```
    L.InfrastructurePopup = L.Popup.extend({

    setContent: function (layer)
    {
        var template = "<form id='popup-form'>\
        <div>\
        <label for='problem'>Problème Identifié</label>\
        <textarea id='" + layer._leaflet_id + "-problem' rows='4' cols='46' placeholder='Type your text here'></textarea>\
        </div>\
        <div>\
        <label for='solution'>Solution Proposée</label>\
        <textarea id='" + layer._leaflet_id + "-solution' rows='4' cols='46' placeholder='Type your text here'></textarea>\
        </div>\
        <button id='" + layer._leaflet_id + "-button-submit' class='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Submit</button>\
        </form>";

        this._content = template;
        this.update();
        return this;
    },
    initializeForm: function(layer, callback)
    {
        console.log(L.DomUtil.get(layer._leaflet_id+'-problem'));
        var problem = L.DomUtil.get(layer._leaflet_id + '-problem');
        problem.textContent = layer.options.problem ? layer.options.problem : "";
        problem.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
        {
            layer.options.problem = problem.value;
        });
        var solution = L.DomUtil.get(layer._leaflet_id + '-solution');
        solution.textContent = layer.options.solution ? layer.options.solution : "";
        solution.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
        {
            layer.options.solution = solution.value;
        });

        var buttonSubmit = L.DomUtil.get(layer._leaflet_id + '-button-submit');
        buttonSubmit.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
        {
            callback(layer);
        });
    }
});

L.infrastructurePopup = function (options, source)
{
    return new L.InfrastructurePopup(options, source);
};
```

Calling setContent when creating my InfrastructurePopup with the layer_id and set it into my template made it work.

I got : '97-problem' or '99-problem' and '97-solution' or '99-solution